# How to search for a text with Active Record in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I search for a string in Ruby on Rails?

For example, all records with columns that contains "text".

Does Active Record have a method for it or do I have to use SQL "LIKE" for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sql `like` may be very inefficient in some cases, for example [in many cases in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). I recommend using some full-text indexing software like Sphinx, Xapian or Lucene.

Comment: so there is no way in Active Record to search for one string in every tables and their columns?

Comment: Searching in all tables could be performed with raw query like this: `SELECT 'table1' AS table_name, id FROM table1 WHERE c1 LIKE "%text%" OR c2 LIKE "%text%" UNION ALL SELECT 'table2' AS table_name, id FROM table2 WHERE c3 LIKE "%text%"`, but I wouldn't do that, it is totally awkward. If you are using MySQL, it has some full-text indexing capabilities - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html - but I don't know how good is it. I don't know about full-text search support in other relational DBs. Recapitulating - AR won't help, use full-text indexing software if you can.

Comment: Just found a sec ago, it may help you http://snowgiraffe.com/rdocs/ar-extensions/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Answer (score 11):

```
 Model.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{tag}%"])
```

Where tag is your variable containing the string

as per @bjg comment:-

Or in Rails 3 you'd write this as

```
  Model.where(["name LIKE :tag", {:tag => tag}])
```

using the new finder syntax –

Comment: Or in Rails 3 you'd write this as `Model.where(["name LIKE :tag", {:tag => tag}])` using the new finder syntax

Comment: but how do i tell RoR3 to search in ALL columns for that model not just in "name" column?

Comment: @never_had_a_name check sphinx search engine for that. Check thinking sphinx http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx

Comment: The given RoR syntax didn't work for me.  `Model.where('last_name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%")`

Answer (score 3):

you can also use Arel's 'match' method:

```
Model.match(:name => tag)
```

if you want to search in all columns, then you should write some extra code.

Comment: Not working for me either. Using `arel`, I would write the query like so: `Model.where(Model.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{query_string}%"))`

Answer (score 3):

If you are deploying to heroku or don't mind dropping db agnosticism, postgres has full text search support. You won't need to run an additional service. Besides PG is the best OS database.
http://tenderlove.github.com/texticle/

Answer (score 2):

I think acts_as_ferret plugin would be perfect for your needs, this plugin allow you to configure easily very cool indexes like

```
ActsAsFerret::define_index( 'my_index',
                        :models => {
                          SomeModel => {
                            :fields => {
                              :name => { :boost => 4, :store => :yes, :via => :ferret_title },
                              :foo => { :store => :no,  :index => :untokenized },
                              :baz => { :store => :yes, :via => :ferret_content }
                            }
                          }
                        } )
```

All acts_as_ferret indexes are configured in a single file, RAILS_ROOT/config/aaf.rb

- find this tutorial it looks nice
  [full text search in ruby on rails 3
  (ferret)](http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2006/10/18/full-text-search-in-ruby-on-rails-3-ferret)
- Github source: http://github.com/jkraemer/acts_as_ferret/tree/rails3
- The original plugin: http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac/wiki/FerretOnRails

Comment: Not only Ferret. Sphinx's thinking-sphinx also integrates with AR nicely. Generally, using full-text indexing software is a good idea.

Comment: Ferret's kind of a pain in the rear. It's slow, it's prone to index corruption, and I had nothing but problems with it. thinking-sphinx is the way to go.